# Can I use a network printer(static IP) connected within ethernet LAN through wifi router?

Tags: networking, router, network-printer, print-server

We have a TP link wifi router which is connected to local ethernet LAN. Our office laptops are connected to wifi router via wifi for internet. My question is, can we access network printer residing in ethernet LAN as well over wifi router from our laptop?
**PS**: My wifi router network and office ethernet LAN are different subnets.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible by default, unless LAN and WiFi router are in different subnets.

Comment: @HarijithR they are different subnets

Answer (score 1):

If you connect it to the Ethernet LAN port of your wifi router it will work. Otherwise, try to keep it in the same subnet, for example, 192.168.0.xxx or any other. You just need the first three numbers the same on your laptops and on your printer. Like I already said the easiest way to get it up and working is to plug it into your wifi router.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: they are different subnets. I do have access to router credentials however, but I am not allowed to change any machines IP address at the moment

Comment: As I said before you could just plug the printer into the LAN port of your TPLink wifi router. If not possible you will need to allow traffic from wifi net to printer IP from your main router. This proces variaes from router to router. I have the most experience with pfSense, but if I can I will try to help you with your current setup. So if you need any help, please tell me what router you are using and which OS it runs if it was ever changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to make physical changes into office network system and I have no access to main router . Anyway I can achieve this within wifi router config?

Comment: It depends on your setup. If it is not working now, there sadly isn't an easy way to get it running at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If all network devices connected each other then just assign secondary IP to you WLAN device. then connect your printer.

Comment: Thanks very much @Sanjay! Any tutorial links how can setup static secondary IP address in TPlink wifi router?

Comment: Hope this will help you ```https://tunecomp.net/windows-10-multiple-ip-addresses/```